# Как переписать данные одного столбца попарно в новый df (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть таблица:

```
  c1  
0  A  
1  B  
2  C  
3  D  
4  E  
5  F
```

Индексы этой таблицы нужно переписать в новую попарно:

```
  c1 c2
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
```

Comment: у вас гарантировано четное число строк?

Comment: нет, но сойдет способ и для четного кол-ва.

Comment: а что делать с лишней строкой в случае нечетного к-ва строк?

Comment: записать ее в паре с ' ', если можно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import zip_longest
pd.DataFrame(list(zip_longest(d.index[::2], d.index[1::2])), columns=['c1','c2'])
```

Пример для четного числа строк:

```
In [116]: d
Out[116]:
  c1
0  A
1  B
2  C
3  D
4  E
5  F

In [117]: from itertools import zip_longest

In [118]: pd.DataFrame(list(zip_longest(d.index[::2], d.index[1::2])), columns=['c1','c2'])
Out[118]:
   c1  c2
0   0   1
1   2   3
2   4   5
```

Пример для нечетного числа строк:

```
In [119]: d2
Out[119]:
  c1
0  A
1  B
2  C
3  D
4  E

In [120]: pd.DataFrame(list(zip_longest(d2.index[::2], d2.index[1::2])), columns=['c1','c2'])
Out[120]:
   c1   c2
0   0  1.0
1   2  3.0
2   4  NaN
```

Comment: Спасибо, выручил)

Comment: @Vlad, пожалуйста! :)